# how to get access token for here-api using postman

Tags: postman, here-api

don't give me this link https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/using-postman.html guide in this link in not working with postman

my postman version
[image]

**my valid Credentials.propeties**
here.access.key.id = V0qAiqfSzIFVv5dPjZ3XmQ
here.access.key.secret=XualuioK9BU9gxw5xjN3oViSRb6HPgTiWsWG5bBWL5G7kr5nsJpoWpCsli5ISQnQ8JlrX2mScSOdDqJAnKvIGA
here.token.endpoint.url = https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token
**same as in guide my Authorization**
[image]
**Headers**
[image]
**Body**
[image]

**Response from server**
[image]
**Console detailed log about request**
[image]

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport can you please explain why it not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Authorization tab I see you have checked "Add empty parameters to signature" and unchecked "Encode the parameters in the Authorization header".

[your Auth tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9067N.png)

Only "Encode the parameters in the Authorization header" should be checked.

Let me know if that fixes it. I also verified this still works with the latest version of Postman v7.34.0 .

Disclosure: I'm a product manager at HERE Technologies

Comment: thank you, yes that solve my problem , Encode the parameters in Authorization header must be checked, add empty parameters to signature must be unchecked.