# Unable to access HERE API with Bearer authorization

Tags: http, here-api, bearer-token

I am trying to access [HERE API example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html) with JetBrains with HTTP files. When I write request this way

```
GET https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=52.5228,13.4124&q=petrol+station&limit=5
Authorization: Bearer {{API_KEY}}
```

I am getting an error

```
{
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "error_description": "Token Validation Failure - unrecognized kid null"
}
```

And while I am accessing with

```
GET https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?apiKey={{API_KEY}}&at=52.5228,13.4124&q=petrol+station&limit=5
```

I am getting a normal answer.

Why? Is it just wrong documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use your bearer token generated from OAUTH,  you can check this post to generate the bearer token from [postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64593999/how-to-get-access-token-for-here-api-using-postman) or with [Python](https://developer.here.com/tutorials/how-to-use-here-oauth-with-python/#request-an-access-token).

```
 https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=52.5228,13.4124&q=petrol+station&limit=5
Authorization: Bearer {Use your Bearer access token}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use "Authorization: Bearer" method don't use API_KEY, but YOUR_TOKEN that you get from OAUTH, more info in documentation https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html